# How to route traffic originating from a specific interface?

Tags: routing, openwrt

On my OpenWRT router I have three interfaces, a WAN interface `wan`, a LAN interface `eth0`, and a OpenVPN interface `tun0`. I want to route all traffic originating from `eth0` to a particular IP address (let's say A.B.C.D) to go through the `tun0` interface instead of directly through `wan`. How should I do that? Is `ip route` the correct command to use here? I tried

```
ip route add to A.B.C.D via [tun0 IP] dev tun0
```

on the router but it seems *all* traffic (instead of just those from `eth0`) are routed this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using Route won't work as you are wanting to manipulate traffic on a criteria other then just the destination IP address - you need to configure policy routing - which allows you to have multiple routing tables and then select which table you wish to use (usually using IPTables marks).